# Why is this Python membership test not false?

Tags: python

Python 3.7:
Why does

```
{'A'} not in {'A'}
```

evaluate to true?

Shouldn't the correct answer be 'false'?
{'A'}.is

Following code does work for me:

```
not {'A'}.issubset({'A'})
```

But I'd like to understand why the first one won't.

Comment: Sets are not, generally speaking, *contained in themselves*.

Comment: `in` for sets is elementhood, not the subset relation. `<=` is the subset relation.

Comment: `in` means ∈, not ⊆.

Comment: OT: A _Python_ set cannot contain itself, because sets are unhashable. Surprisingly, some Python data structures (such as lists) can recur on themselves, but this seems to depend on the data structure both supporting unhashable members, and also being mutable themselves. (So, at first I thought maybe a frozenset could recur, but since it isn't mutable, I guess it can't.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks, "in means ∈, not ⊆" solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
({'A'} not in {'A'}) is True
({'A'} in {'B', frozenset({'A'})}) is True
{'A'}.issubset({'A'}) is True
('A' not in {'A'}) is False
```

`{'A'}` doesn't literally contain the set `{'A'}`. It contains `'A'`. `{frozenset({'A'})}`, however, does contain an inner set `frozenset({'A'})` *and* a string `'B'`. It's not possible to write `{{'A'}}` because that would require that the inner set be hashable, but sets are not hashable, while `frozenset`s are.

Also `{'A'}` is a *subset* of itself, which is different from it literally containing a copy of itself.

Answer (score 0):

So, `'A'` is a string, while `{'A'}` is a set, containing a string `'A'`. Your right operand `{'A'}` does not contain your left operand `{'A'}` (it only contains `'A'`), so the whole expression is true. But if you write `'A' not in {'A'}`, the result would be `False`.